# macOS Catalyst Application not showing up in iTunes/App Store Connect Build Options

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

I have created a macOS application from an already existing iOS application. I checked the checkbox to enable macOS support and it added the sandbox entitlement just like the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app) said.

[image]

In the developer's page I also see that macOS support is enabled.

[image]

My iOS app appears in iTunes Connect and passes reviews. So far everything seems to be great.

[image]

My Catalyst app isn't so lucky. No builds show up under Activity.

[image]

[image]

How do I get my build to show up in iTunes Connect? Do I have to submit the macOS app differently than my regular iOS/iPad app in Xcode Organizer? I am happy to provide any other information to help solve this.

Comment: Same here. Did you solve the problem? We have uploaded archive built with My Mac destination but none show up under Activity.

Comment: @fishpotato the accepted answer worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make a separate archive for the macOS version and then upload that separate archive from the Organizer. To create the archive, make sure you select My Mac as the destination. The Organizer will show your iOS app and your Mac apps separately.

This is covered in part in the [WWDC 2019 #235 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/235).